# Convert word or half-word to bytes in C# or Lua?

Tags: c#, lua

I have an external Lua interface that forms packets as below:

```
Packet1 is..0x0111
Packet2 is..0x001C
Header1 is..0x001C0111   (Packet1 + packet 2)
Packet3 is..0x0F00
Packet4 is..0x0000
Header2 is..0x00000F00    (Packet3 + packet 4)
Packet5 is..0x0001
Packet6 is..0xEFD1
Header3 is..0xEFD10001   (Packet5 + packet 6)
Packet7 is..0x0000
Packet8 is..0x000C
Header4 is..0x000C0000  (Packet7 + packet 8)
```

This is a variable packet length (I have shown 8 2-byte packets and 4 4-byte headers ) formed from these packets. The length might be anything based on the packet formed. I need to send this info as bytes to another function that operates on these bytes. I need to send bytes in a particular order in byte format to that function. Can someone help how do I achieve this conversion in c# or in Lua ?